# Folium Problem: "No module named 'folium.map'; 'folium' is not a package"

Tags: python, data-visualization, data-science, folium

A few days ago Folium was working perfectly, but now it's not working. The problem:

```
import folium

    ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-173c1173bf1c> in <module>
----> 1 import folium

~\folium.py in <module>
     13 from branca.element import CssLink, Element, Figure, JavascriptLink, MacroElement
     14 
---> 15 from folium.map import FitBounds
     16 from folium.raster_layers import TileLayer
     17 from folium.utilities import _parse_size, _tmp_html, _validate_location

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folium.map'; 'folium' is not a package
```

Even installing by pip and conda doesn't matter library.

Comment: Here the `folium` package is itself not installed. What is the environment you are using? You need to install `folium` for use in that environment. Just run `import folium` for verification after installation.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Jupyter Notebook. I installed both pip and conda, but this error occurs up there. About 10 days ago it was working, but it is no longer.

Comment: Run `pip list | grep "folium"` on your terminal and post the result.